# Error in stop("animation of ", class(plot)[1], " objects not supported") : argument "plot" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I want to animate the bars of each cuntry for their energy production through out the 3 years. Wrote the below code but I am getting an error.

```
library(gganimate)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(energyProd_Distribution, aes(country_name,ggwt_hours,color=country_name, fill = country_name))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)+
  labs(x = "Year", y="Energy Production(GWh)", title = "Analysis of the Energy Production between 2016 to 2018", fill = "Year", color = "Year")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.position="top")+
  transition_states(year)+
  animate(renderer = gifski_renderer())

Error in stop("animation of ", class(plot)[1], " objects not supported") : 
  argument "plot" is missing, with no default

    > dput(head(energyProd_Distribution))
structure(list(country = c("DE", "DE", "DE", "FR", "FR", "FR"
), country_name = c("Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "France", 
"France", "France"), year = c("2016", "2017", "2018", "2016", 
"2017", "2018"), ggwt_hours = c(619606, 624969, 578460.796, 545060.548, 
542597.798, 560767.871)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    country = c("DE", "FR"), .rows = structure(list(1:3, 4:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Can anyone help me to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be several ways to fix it. This works on my machine:

```
library(gganimate)
library(ggplot2)

gr <- ggplot(energyProd_Distribution, aes(country_name, ggwt_hours, color = country_name, fill = country_name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  labs(
    x = "Year",
    y = "Energy Production(GWh)",
    title = "Analysis of the Energy Production between 2016 to 2018",
    fill = "Year",
    color = "Year"
  ) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  transition_states(year) 

animate(gr, renderer = gifski_renderer())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, try something like: `animate(gr, width = 800, height = 600) `

Comment: Actually I have mistakenly deleted the previous comment. Sorry. Thank you for all the answers. It is really cool.